# Remote branch was deleted accidently when force-push?

Tags: git

I wonder why was a remote branch deleted when I force-push my local branch, like this:

```
git push upstream localbranch:test -f
```

after this cmd, the remote branch is shown:

```
- [deleted] test
```

Could anyone actually know what's going on with this situation?

Normally the local branch should to push to remote as the test branch, so I can make test.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is localbranch the actual name of your local branch?

Comment: no, git push upstream rewrite-display:test -f